# What is the importance of ranks

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

What is the importance of leveling up the ranks in tiny death star ? It helps on ordering timing or how much money each product prosuces ? What does it actually do ?

Comment: My advice is to upgrade your rank on the Imperial Court Level only and only stock the third item "execution" and use the VIP big spender to redeem it. I have this level at about a 76 rank now (from buying random vips) and each time I use a big spender it gives me 460k or so in credits

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you increase the rank of a level in tiny death star all you do is upgrade the amount of stock that the level can hold.

It does not affect the ordering timing or the amount of money.

Example:

- Rank 1 = **Can order 100 products**
- Rank 5 = **Can order 140 products**

I don't find it very useful as I only upgrade ranks from VIP's but it could be great in the future.

Comment: Does this also affect the time of ordering ?

Comment: Duration of ordering (and selling) goes up.  The speed doesn't change.  If ordering 100 products = 10 minutes, then ordering 140 products = 14 minutes.

Comment: @WilliamC I don't think that's true. I've never seen the ordering time go up, including just now when I upgraded Bounty Hunters from 4 to 5, and the 37 minute ordering for 650 units of carbonite freezing became 37 minute ordering for 700 units. What do you base your statement on?